# when we open the code in console browser all the mobile number should be display i did not want this? how to hide this from console?

Tags: javascript

After View console all the mobile no showing how can I resolved it?

```
  var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($allmobone); ?>;

var mob = document.getElementById("user_mobile_number").value;

var precode = "91";
mobcode = precode + mob;

for (var r = 0; r < jArray.length; r++) {
    if (jArray[r] == mobcode) {
        document.getElementById("spn_user_mobile_number_2").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not want to show JArray data on view source on chrome

Comment: Could you rephrase the question?, not really getting what your asking..

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. Do you want the `jArray` to be invisible in the browser console? Or do you want nobody to know the `jArray` value?

Comment: thanks man, I want atleast this value invisible in the browser console

Comment: You can't hide from the Chrome «View source» tool anything you send to browser. If you need to hide something, keep it on the server, e.g. check a mobile code by sending an AJAX request to the server.

Comment: I think Ajax Req is better solution for this

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hide the `$allmobone` value completely from a browser developer tools, don't send it to clients. Instead send an AJAX request to the server when you need to check a mobile number, and make a decision depending on the request response.

Here is an HTML code of the page with the user interface:

```
function ajaxGet(url, onload, onerror) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            onload(request.responseText);
        } else {
            onerror();
        }
    };
    request.onerror = onerror;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send();
}

var mob = document.getElementById("user_mobile_number").value;

var precode = "91";
mobcode = precode + mob;

ajaxGet('/checkMobileCode.php?mobcode=' + encodeURIComponent(mobcode), function (response) {
    if (response === 'ok') {
       document.getElementById("spn_user_mobile_number_2").style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

And here is a PHP code of the script which checks a mobile code (`/checkMobileCode.php`):

```
if (in_array($_GET['mobcode'] ?? '', $allmobone)) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Use Ajax to load your resources dynamically, then viewing source (ctrl+u) will not show any values:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getJson.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (jArray) {
        var mob = document.getElementById("user_mobile_number").value;

        var precode = "91";
        mobcode = precode + mob;

        for (var r = 0; r < jArray.length; r++) {
            if (jArray[r] == mobcode) {
                document.getElementById("spn_user_mobile_number_2").style.display = "block";
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
});
```

But there still be visible response in console network tab

---

Option 2:
If you have only static data, then loop your data and apply inline css:

```
<?php

foreach ($allmobone as $el) {
    if ($el === $_POST['mobcode']) {
        echo "<div id='spn_user_mobile_number_2'>...</div>";
    }
}
```

Only that you have to submit form when user enters "mobcode" to reload page.